# What Java code should I use so that the user can't press the return button on their device and return to the previous activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, return

I have created a simple android quiz app. Where the user takes a quiz and then the app takes them to a result screen where they can see exactly which questions that they got wrong. However at the moment the user can simply go back to the question page (the previous activity) and change their answers what code could I use to prevent this from happening.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If your quiz questions are displayed via one activity, and your results are displayed via another activity, when you call `startActivity()` to show the results activity, also call `finish()` to destroy the questions activity.